# Releases UI thread while long method is running using await and async

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm starting to explore async and wait keywords from c# 5.0 so i made a few test using winforms, but now i'm stuck in a situation:

My point is to run a query from a database and while the query is not completed i want to show a loading gif on form.

This is the method that queries the database:

```
public static async Task<List<string>> GetItensFromDatabase()
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>();

        using (ServerConn)
        {
            ServerConn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Names", ServerConn);

            var ds = new DataSet();
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(ds); // this call lasts about 1 minute

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                names.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
            }
        }
        return names;
    }
```

And i call that method here:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> itens = null;
        itens = await AsyncMethods.GetItensFromDatabase(); // I want that the form dont be stuck here

        ShowItensInListView(itens);
    }
```

For now i have a omnipresent loading image gif on the form that is rotating until the method GetItensFromDatabase be called, when the method is running the gif is stop and when the method finishes the gif start rotating again.

So, theres some way to keep the gif rotating while the GetItensFromDatabase method is running ?

Comment: Just slapping `async` to a method won't make it automagically asynchronous/non-blocking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have used the `await` keyword inside your `async` method, but since there is no awaitable operation, you should create a `Task` explicitly inside your method using the `TaskFactory`:

```
public static Task<List<string>> GetItensFromDatabase()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew<List<string>>(() => 
    { 
        List<string> names = new List<string>();

        using (ServerConn)
        {
            ServerConn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Names", ServerConn);

            var ds = new DataSet();
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(ds); // this call lasts about 1 minute

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                names.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
            }
        }
        return names;
    });
}
```

Edit: As @mmarques points out, another (better) solution is to use `SqlDataReader` instead of `SqlDataAdapter`. The reason is that `SqlDataReader` has `async` methods available - meaning you don't need to use `TaskFactory` to block a new thread from the thread pool, and you can use `async` and `await`.

```
public static async Task<List<string>> GetItensFromDatabase()
{
    List<string> names = new List<string>();

    using (ServerConn)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Names", ServerConn))
        {
            ServerConn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(reader);

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    names.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return names;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with "You could have used the await keyword inside your async method, but since there is no awaitable operation...."
So, what you trying to say is that if i have some long loop (for example) i could use the await keyword inside that loop to releases the Ui thread ? something like this: await Task.Delay(200);

Comment: @johnnycardy, you should not be offloading **synchronous IO-bound operations** to a pool thread with `Task.Factory.StartNew`. You should instead use `async` APIs provided by ADO.NET and `await` on their results.

Comment: @Noseratio Where are the `async` APIs provided by ADO.NET? I haven't come across any

Comment: @mmarques - Yes, `async` is useless if there's no `await` in the method. Check out this blog post by Eric Lippert: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/28/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-one.aspx

Comment: @johnnycardy, there're at least two options: 1) [new ADO.NET async APIs in v4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/20/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta.aspx), 2) existing async APIs like [`SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szdt0kc(v=vs.110).aspx), which can easily be turned into awaitable `Task`-style APIs with [APM pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/09/9716439.aspx?Redirected=true).

Comment: @mmarques cool, I hadn't seen those. Updated the answer. Feel free to edit if you spot anything else.

Comment: @johnnycardy: When you're using `async`, think about what each method is doing and whether there's an `async` way of doing it. E.g., the solution should use `ServerConn.OpenAsync`, and `ReadAsync` in a loop instead of `DataTable.Load`.